# Can PCT application based on US provisional patent without claim?

Tags: claims, provisional-application, pct

AFAIK, US provisional patent is valid for later use even without any claim, but I heard that some countries require patent having claims. So does PCT application accepts US provisional patent without claim as valid priority date?

Or should I file US provisional with claims (like a formal patent application)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, definitely. The PCT accepts US provisional application without any claims. However, it is always advisable to write some broad claims in the Provisional application. It is just an added measure.

Comment: could you please cite rule or article which states PCT application can be filed without claims??

Comment: The questioner themselves have stated so in their question.

Comment: in my understanding no PCT rule or article states that a application can be filed without claim.